# Using software from module system with VS Code and CMake Tools

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, module, cluster-computing, system

**The Problem**

In scientific contexts, many software/libraries are not installed on the system but loaded from a module system.

Then, in order to use another gcc compiler, you would do:

module load .../gcc-X

or for hdf5

module load ../hdf5-Y

Sometimes also meta modules or programming environments

module load ProgrammingEnvironmentX

are available that set up a lot of libraries and links between them.

Then, I can perfectly configure and build a project with CMake and the loaded modules *inside a terminal*.

However, if I use VSCode and the CMakeTools Extension via the graphical user interface, it is unclear to me, how VSCode learns about these modules and the paths set.

I thought that the CMake extension would read a compile_commands.json in the corresponding root directory as it magically worked some hours ago but I cannot reproduce it.

I know that I can set the kit or compiler via F1 and "CMake: Edit User-Local CMake Kits". However, this only resolves for the compiler not for additional software such as hdf5 or gdb and its links.

**Question**

How can I configure, build and debug a software with VSCode and CMakeTools Extension if I do not use system software but variable modules? For the compiler, this is clear to me, see the kits. But often you need much more than just another compiler.

**A potential solution**

I am not sure if the solution presented in the following always works.

Load your software modules, e.g., with `module load PrgEnv/gcc11-openmpi` in a terminal and start code from that same terminal (If you use VSCode Remote you may need to load these modules in your bashrc and maybe kill the vscode-server everytime you disconnect and when you want to load other modules; not sure though)

There is the possibility to set specific compilers as a kit in `cmake-tools-kits.json`. Press F1 and go to `CMake: Edit User-Local CMake Kits` and, e.g., add

```
  {
    "name": "GCC 11 openmpi",
    "compilers": {
      "C": "/modulesystem/...LONGPATH.../bin/gcc",
      "CXX": "/modulesystem/...LONGPATH.../bin/g++"
    }
  }
```

or similar if you have, e.g., loaded a clang/clang++ compiler set.

Then add to your settings.json (also in .vscode of your project directory)

```
"cmake.cmakePath" : "...LONGPATH.../bin/cmake",
"cmake.debugConfig": {
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "...LONGPATH.../bin/gdb"
    }
```

If you don't do so, CMakeTools or VSCode will try to use the system CMake in the first case or search for gdb in the compiler path set above in the kit.

**Some other promising approaches *without solution* **

*Approach A: CMake Tools Kits with environmentSetupScript*

If we do not want to load one particular module environment but change without restarting VSCode, we could load the environment before the call of cmake tools with the script

```
#!/bin/bash
module load PrgEnv/gcc11-openmpi
```

and execute this with

```
"environmentSetupScript": "/home/USER/.load_gcc11.sh",
```

which is placed below `"name": "GCC 11 openmpi",` above. However, in my case I get a lot of

```
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: }
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: ;;
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: ;;
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: ;;
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: *)
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: ;;
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: }
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: ;;
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: ;;
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: ;;
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: *)
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: ;;
[kit] Error parsing environment variable: }
```

I actually do not know what then was set correctly and what not. This however could be solved as reported in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/2686

*Approach B: Using tasks.json*

I also tried to set up a tasks.json and to call a task like

```
{
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "Build with modules",
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/cpp/"
    },
    "command": "module load PrgEnv/gcc11-openmpi; cd build; cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..; cmake --build . -- -j32; gdb build/bin/ode_secir_save_result",
    "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "cpp",
        "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceFolder}"],
        "pattern": {
          "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
          "file": 1,
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "severity": 4,
          "message": 5
        }
    }
}
```

This also perfectly builds all software parts but CMake Tools extensions does not get to know about these. I could not resolve that with a particular launch.json or whatsoever on top of that.

Comment: Where you able to find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not :-/
I went around with the potential solution/workaround from above so far.